# Выпадающее подменю

Tags: css, jsp

Как сделать так что бы выпадающее подменю выпадало вниз друг за другом? А то у меня слева на право.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*| Navigation |*/

nav.navig {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #b5cd60;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: inline-table;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

nav.navig ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig .sub li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  height: 50px;
}

nav.navig ul li:hover>.sub {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}

nav.navig ul li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul ul {
  display: none;
  background: #b5cd60;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navig" role='navigation'>
  <ul>

    <li><a href="index.jsp">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Просмотр данных</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="SkisqlController?action=list&page=1">Просмотр Skisql</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Просмотр Skisql2</a></li>


      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Добавить данные</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="SkisqlController?action=skisql">Добавление Skisql</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Добавление Skisql2</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <form class="frm" method="post" name="frm" action="Search">
        <input type="text" size="25px" name="kiz" id="kiz" align="middle" placeholder="Введите код изготовления">
        <input class="search" type="submit" name="submit" value="  Поиск  "></form>
    </li>
    <li>
      <form class="frm" method="post" name="exit" action="login.jsp">

        <input class="exit" type="submit" name="submit" value="  Выход  "></form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `float` применяется для всех `li` в теге `ul`, т.е. и для дочерних. Как вариант - просто добавить стиль для всех `li` в теге `ul` с классом `sub` который будет обнулять `float` свойство

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*| Navigation |*/

nav.navig {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #b5cd60;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: inline-table;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

nav.navig ul.sub li {
  float: initial;
}

nav.navig ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig .sub li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  height: 50px;
}

nav.navig ul li:hover>.sub {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

nav.navig ul li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul ul {
  display: none;
  background: #b5cd60;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  height: 70px;
}

nav.navig ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navig" role='navigation'>
  <ul>

    <li><a href="index.jsp">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Просмотр данных</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="SkisqlController?action=list&page=1">Просмотр Skisql</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Просмотр Skisql2</a></li>


      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Добавить данные</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="SkisqlController?action=skisql">Добавление Skisql</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Добавление Skisql2</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <form class="frm" method="post" name="frm" action="Search">
        <input type="text" size="25px" name="kiz" id="kiz" align="middle" placeholder="Введите код изготовления">
        <input class="search" type="submit" name="submit" value="  Поиск  "></form>
    </li>
    <li>
      <form class="frm" method="post" name="exit" action="login.jsp">

        <input class="exit" type="submit" name="submit" value="  Выход  "></form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: почему-то `initial` подчеркивает желтым в netbeanse и ничего не меняется, меню слева на право

Comment: я не знаю что вам там пишет netbeans, но если запустите пример и развернете на весь экран - это то что нужно

Comment: @СергейНиконенкону, а вообще можно заменить `float: initial;` на `clear: both;`

Comment: с эти работает `clear: both;` спасибо большое